# Why to define an empty variable?

Tags: php

I just need to know why in some cases we need to define an empty variable because i am facing this type of variables many times and they developer keep saying it is to avoid errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [PHP docs on language variable basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) (emphasis mine):

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP **however it is a very good practice**. Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array.
>
> ...
>
> Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is problematic in the case of including one file into another which uses the same variable name. It is also a major security risk with register_globals turned on.

-- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't understand the manual statements i understand more from examples because the manual talking to programmers which i am still a beginner

Comment: If you don't set a variable's value to an empty value at the time you create the variable, then the variable might have a value set previously from some unexpected source. So it's a good idea to set variables to empty when you create them.

Comment: So it is for safety if some other sources may have the same variable with a value which would be used by my code. so i define it once more to make sure it is empty . some says that if your are making a condition you better use this way to avoid having an undefined variable in case of condition failure . what would you say about this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It works that way in some languages, but not in PHP.

Comment: Oh right. So why does `$var++` not work reliably unless you init `$var = 0;` first. I am interested not trying to be an assole. Probably because it does not know what type it is until it is used